# What's the stat difference between a Pokemon hatched with 6IV to a Pokemon whose IVs are from Hyper Training?

Tags: pokemon-scarlet-violet

This would be the first time I would attempt to get a 'perfect' Pokemon, but there is one mechanic that puzzles me so: Hyper Training. I would like to know if there is a range of difference between the stats of a Pokemon that was hatched with 6IV when compared to another Pokemon that was Hyper Trained.

Suppose I have two Pokemon— say, a Dunsparce— that are identical in every which way (EVs, Nature, etc.) except for how they attained the 6IV status. One from breeding, and the other, Hyper Training. Would this result in a big stat difference between them once I got them to later levels? Or would they ultimately have the same stats in the end?

Comment: +1 for the Dunsparce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not ultimately. They will immediately gets same stats when you hyper-trained a Pokemon.

Leveled stats only gets affected by [EV (Effort Values)](https://www.serebii.net/games/evs.shtml), which can be increased by battling wild Pokemons / using Vitamins and Feathers, and decreased by using certain Berries (I suppose the Vitamins / Feathers / Berries works same as Sword / Shield, but I'm not completely sure). Information for SV are found at [here](https://www.serebii.net/scarletviolet/effortvalues.shtml).

However, quote from [this page](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Hyper_Training)(emphasis mine):

> Rather than actually changing a Pokémon's IVs, Hyper Training sets a modifier for the game to treat that stat as if it had an IV of 31. **As a result, it affects neither the type of Hidden Power the Pokémon has nor the IVs it can pass down when breeding.**

Since (as of now) SV doesn't have Hidden Power so you don't need to worry about it, though if you want to breed 6IV by using hyper-trained Pokemons (which I personally think there's no reason to do so), they won't get transferred by breeding.

Comment: FWIW, Hidden Power was removed Sword/Shield and wasn’t never re-added through the DLC. So I highly doubt SV will get Hidden Power

Comment: I am aware that, but no one can say they'll never gets added. As you said, in SwSh you couldn't learn Hidden Power, but their in-game move list had Hidden Power so communities was thinking it'll get added at some point (as you said it never happened though). I haven't checked if SV's move list has it, but there's possibility it has.